# How to use a jQuery dependent node module in React.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

I want to use this library in my React application: http://propeller.in, but it's built on jQuery. I have added the following relevant code in my Index.js React component:

```
import $ from 'jquery';
import 'propellerkit/dist/js/propeller.js';
```

I've also tried this:

```
import 'jquery/dist/js/jquery.js';
import 'propellerkit/dist/js/propeller.js';
```

I've made sure both node modules are installed. For some reason, I keep getting a `$ is not defined` error.

Comment: You can try `import * as $ from 'jquery';` but since I did not I didn't find it worthy of a top level answer.

Comment: Thanks, but same error.

Comment: Did you try `import * as $ from 'jquery/dist/js/jquery.js';` or just `import 'jquery';`? That should expose jQuery as a "global" in the dist webpack creates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using webpack to bundle, you can provide `jquery` using `ProvidePlugin`,

```
new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
  $: 'jquery',
  jQuery: 'jquery'   // this will try to find node jquery module
})
```

Link to [docs](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/provide-plugin/)

Comment: Perfect. Thanks!

Comment: can you let me know how can I add a plugin in web pack in create react app...?